# EAS update doesn't update landing page QR

Tags: react-native, expo, eas, expo-go

I developed a React Native application using Expo.
I finished my application and used "eas build" to upload the app.
It built my site with a QR that when I scan it in my phone the up launches.

After a while, I updated my app and wanted to update the QR on the landing page.

I tried to use "eas update".
It updated the app in my private zone on Expo site, but the QE on the landing page didn't change.

How can I update that QR?
How to set it updated as the expo repository?
Is there any way to do that for free?